# How do i make a function repeat after a time delay in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to retrieve data from node location if the location node exists. If it is present, I want it to read the values latitude and longitude and change the location of the marker on the map. This step has to repeat every 5 seconds.
Now, it retrieves data once. I want it to keep repeating only if the location node is available

This is the current code

```
        busReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                usercount = ds.getChildrenCount();
                for(int i = 1; i <= usercount; i++){
                    if(ds.hasChild(userid)){
                        busno = ds.getKey();
                        driverReference = mDatabaseReference.child("Busno").child(busno);

                        driverReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for(DataSnapshot ds1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                    if(ds1.hasChild("location")) {



                                            driverid = ds1.getKey();

                                            locationReference = mDatabaseReference.child("Busno").child(busno).child(driverid).child("location");

                                            locationReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                    String lat1 = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
                                                    latitude = Double.valueOf(lat1);
                                                    String lon1 = dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
                                                    longitude = Double.valueOf(lon1);
                                                    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                                                    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                                                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Current Location"));
                                                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                                                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                                }
                                            });
                                            break;

                                    }

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether the node exists you can use the below

```
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataSnapshot.exists()//returns true if node exists

          }

          @Override public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            emitter.onError(databaseError.toException());
          }
```

Now if the node exists instead of using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` use `addValueEventListener()` this will give you a callback every time there is a change in the value of the particular node.

Comment: I want the process to repeat after a time delay. That's where I'm struggling

Comment: Time delay does not make sense as whenever value changes the app will be notified.

Comment: But that's not happening. That is why I asked for help regarding a time delay